# Swap words and reformat date in a filename

Tags: sed, rename

I have several recordings with a file-name schema like this

```
%year%month%day-%hour%minute%second__%phonenumber.amr

e.g.:
20190212-112007__+313206601234.amr
```

I want to swap words to obtain:

```
%phonenumber_%day-%month-%year_%hour-%minute-%second.amr

e.g.:
+313206601234__12-02-2019_11-20-07.amr
```

I know I can use `sed` utility but its syntax is like an archaic language, plus I'm confused about the use of both `[0-9] and .` for substitution.

Comment: The archaic language is regular expressions. However `sed` if for file content and streams. `rename` (the Larry Wall version), is `sed` for file-names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about using captured groups of digits, and putting groups at desired places to get the required name:

```
sed -E 's/^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})__(\+[[:digit:]]+)/\7__\3-\2-\1_\4-\5-\6/'
```

- `-E` enables ERE (Extended Regular Expressions)
- `[[:digit:]]` matches a locale-aware digit
- `{N}` matches `N` number of preceding token e.g. `[[:digit:]]{2}` matches 2 digits; this can also be a range e.g. `[[:digit:]]{2,4}` matches 2 to 4 digits

**Example:**

```
% sed -E 's/^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})__(\+[[:digit:]]+)/\7__\3-\2-\1_\4-\5-\6/' <<<'20190212-112007__+313206601234.amr'
+313206601234__12-02-2019_11-20-07.amr
```

Comment: @mattia.b89: With prename (Perl's standalone rename command): `prename -n 's/^([[:digit:]]{4})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{2})__(\+[[:digit:]]+)/$7__$3-$2-$1_$4-$5-$6/' *.amr`. If everything looks fine, remove `-n`.